# Is this predicate logic derivation valid?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

Could someone please be so kind as to check the validity of my predicate derivation? I am trying to prove that the set $\{(\forall x)\lnot(\exists y)Gxy,(\forall z)[Hz\implies(\exists z) Gzy],(\exists w)Hw\}$ is inconsistent, and have so conjured the following derivation:

1. $(\forall x)\lnot(\exists y)Gxy$____Assumption
2. $(\forall z)[Hz\implies(\exists z) Gzy]$____Assumption
3. $(\exists w)Hw$____Assumption
4. Hb____A/$\exists$E
5. Hb $\implies$ ($\exists y$)Gby____2$\forall$E
6. $(\exists y)$Gby____4,5$\implies$E
7. Gba____A/$\exists$E
8. $\lnot$Gab____A/$\lnot$E
9. ($\exists$ y)Gby____7$\exists$I
10. $\lnot(\exists y)$Gby____1$\forall$E
11. Gab____8-10$\lnot$E
12. Gab____7-11$\exists$E
13. ($\exists y$)Gay____12$\exists$I
14. ($\exists y$)Gay____4$\exists$E
15. $\lnot(\exists y)Gay$____1$\forall$E

I ask for this because I am still getting used to predicate proofs, and hence seek affirmation from the more proffesional. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the *exact* rules of the particular proof system you are working with this is a little hard to answer, but my guess is that your system would not allow step 12:  in lines 7-11 you use $a$ as a temporary placeholder for the 'something $y$ for which $Gby$ holds' ... but when you then apply the $\exists E$ rule on those lines 7-11, I bet that you are not allowed to infer any statement that refers to that very $a$, because outside of that context of lines 7-11, $a$ suddenly becomes to mean a specific object.

Fortunately, you don't need any of lines 7-11 in the first place! Note that once you have $(\exists y)Gby$ on line 6, you can apply a $\forall E$ on line 1 to obtain $\neg (\exists y)Gby$ on line 7, so there is your contradiction.

Of course, you still need to 'pull out' this contradiction so it is not within the context of the assumption made on line 4, and unfortunately you don't seem to have an explicit contradiction symbol $\bot$ that you can work with in your system. As such, you will need to do something awkward like *first* assuming $(\exists w)Hw$ on line 4, *then* do everything you did on lines 4-6 (so those become lines 5-7), then do my suggested  $\neg (\exists y)Gby$ on line 8, then get $\neg (\exists y)Gby$ on line 9 by applying $\exists E$ on lines 5-8, and finally get $\neg (\exists w) Hw$ on line 10 by applying $\neg I$ on lines 4-9 (I assume you have a $\neg I$ rule that works like that)

Comment: Oh much thanks! I haven't noticed that I've been using existential elimination incorrectly. Also, I'm still working on my predicate logic skills, so I must ask for some terminological questions. Would you have understood me if I said that the exact rules of my particular proof system is the rules of PD (Predicate Derivation)? The book I'm working with only does introduce it like that.

Comment: @Camelot823 It is clear that you are working with *some* kind of formsl derivation system for predicate logic. However, there are many variants within that class of derivational systems, especially where the use of objects are involved. And with so many different textbooks that are around now, and without much of a standard for naming those different systems, saying that your system is called ‘PD’ tells us nothing about the specifics of the system, and for a *formal* derivation that is all important.

Comment: So then how would I be to specify my formal derivation rules correctly? How would you, namely, do exactly this? Would you simply specify the rules one by one in a list?

Comment: @Camelot823 Unfortunately yes, we’d need a list of all the rules one by one. And yes, that’s a pain, so if you have the ability to link to an online presentation or image of the rules, we’d be happy to work with that.

Answer (score 0):

Lines 9 and 10 are already a contradiction so I don't see why you need any of the subsequent lines.

Comment: It's because there are still undischarged assumptions (lines 4, 7, and 8) at that point

Comment: I guess I don't understand the formal system being used here. Line 4 follows from line 3 by introducing a new symbol $b$ for an element which is asserted to exist in line 3. Similarly, line 7 follows from line 6, and line 8 from line 1. I don't see how there is any "undischarged assumption".

Comment: Well, I could certainly  be wrong myself, not knowing the details of this system either, but I read the big $A$ as part of the justification in lines 4,7, and 8 as an assumption